# How to display value in nearby input text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I have got two input type textboxes

```
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon icon_change"><i class="fa"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control locur" name="locale[]" id="locale" placeholder="Enter the value" maxlength="10" value="" />
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3" id="usr" class="usr">
           <div class="input-group">
           <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-usr"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control usr" name="ustate[]" id="ustate" placeholder="Enter the rate" maxlength="10" value="" />
            </div>
         </div>
```

When I enter values in one text box ,the jquery script I prepared calculates with the vlaues and result should be shown in name="ustate[]" text box

```
   $('.locur').live('change',function(){
   var local_id = $("#curr_id").val();
   var amt = $(this).val();             
   var convertedcost = convert_amt(amt,local_id);
   $(this).find('.usr input[type="text"]').val(convertedcost);
    //$(this).closest('usr').find('input[type="text"]').val(convertedcost);
   });
```

I have tried above script,but it didn't work.

Note: There will be multiple set of these two text boxes as its looped throught a PHP script.

Any solutions ?

Comment: are there multiple sets of these? if not, why couldn't you just did this: `$("#ustate]").val()` ?

Comment: @swadhwa yes there are multiple sets of these.

Comment: `.live` is a deprecated function in jQuery since 1.9 - do not use that. Use `.on` method instead

Comment: Also you can NOT define class attributes in one element `multiple` times - Can you please add what is `curr_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a 'newclass' in the top most div class that will also work.

```
 <div class="col-sm-3 newclass">
       <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon icon_change"><i class="fa"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control locur" name="locale[]" id="locale" placeholder="Enter the value" maxlength="10" value="" />
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3" id="usr" class="usr">
       <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-usr"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control usr" name="ustate[]" id="ustate" 
       placeholder="Enter the rate" maxlength="10" value="" />
     </div>
   </div>
```

then use :

```
$(this).parents(".newclass").first().next().find("#ustate");
```

its better to use a different class name than a bootstrap class name.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to wrap each of these sets with a `div` with a class say `wrap`, like this:

```
 <div class="wrap">
   <div class="col-sm-3">
     <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon icon_change"><i class="fa"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control locur" name="locale[]" id="locale" placeholder="Enter the value" maxlength="10" value="" />
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3" id="usr" class="usr">
       <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-usr"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control usr" name="ustate[]" id="ustate" placeholder="Enter the rate" maxlength="10" value="" />
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

then:

```
$(this).parents(".wrap").first().find("#ustate")
```

without wrapping:

```
$(this).parents(".col-sm-3").first().next().find("#ustate")
```

Comment: Why `wrap` - you can do this without wrapping in a div too.

Comment: ........you can NOT define class attributes in one element `multiple` times. - may be suggest that too.

Comment: is it possible to get result without using div wrap ? if yes, how ?

Comment: maybe try this: `$(this).parents(".col-sm-3").first().next().find("#ustate")`

Comment: Thanks @swadhwa $(this).parents(".col-sm-3").first().next().find("#ustate") this worked for me . Thanks a lot .

Comment: @swadhwa  although $(this).parents(".col-sm-3").first().next().find("#ustate") worked for me. Any other way to use a classname instead of col-sm-3 ,I gave a classname and tried,but didnt work,also tried with new div class wrap and $(this).parents(".wrap").first().find("#ustate") tht also didnt work. .Is there any way to use classname other than bootstrap class?

Comment: @user21488 if `<div class="col-sm-3 locale-parent">` then: `$(this).parents(".locale-parent").first().next().find("#ustate")`